# Permutations of multiple lists in different order

Tags: java, permutation

This are the 3 lists that I'm working on:

```
List<String> first = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
List<String> second = Arrays.asList("X", "Y", "Z");
List<String> third = Arrays.asList("1", "2");
```

My recursive method for all permutations is the following:

```
public static void permute(List<List<String>> lists, List<List<String>> result, int depth, String current) {
    if (depth == lists.size()) {
        List<String> current_list = new ArrayList<>();
        current_list = current.chars().mapToObj(e -> Character.toString((char)e))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
         result.add(current_list);
         return;
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < lists.get(depth).size(); i++) {
         permute(lists, result, depth + 1, current + lists.get(depth).get(i));
     }
}
```

It gives me the following result:

```
[[a, X, 1], [a, X, 2], [a, Y, 1], [a, Y, 2], [a, Z, 1], [a, Z, 2], [b, X, 1], [b, X, 2], [b, Y, 1], [b, Y, 2], [b, Z, 1], [b, Z, 2]]
```

How can I change the method so that I get this result instead:

```
[[a,X, 1], [b, X, 1], [a, Y, 1], [b, Y, 1], [a, Z, 1], [b, Z, 1], [a, X, 2], [b, X, 2], [a, Y, 2], [b, Y, 2], [a, Z, 2], [b, Z, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not updated your logic but I saw few pattern the the combination happened at the base condition so change the order the input taken in the list and reverse the current list before storing in result.

```
public class Stack {

    static List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> first = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
        List<String> second = Arrays.asList("X", "Y", "Z");
        List<String> third = Arrays.asList("1", "2");
        
        List<List<String>> permute = new ArrayList<>();
        
        
        
        permute.add(new ArrayList<>(third));
        permute.add(new ArrayList<>(second));
        permute.add(new ArrayList<>(first));
        
        permute(permute,result,0,"");
        
        for(List<String> re : result) {
            System.out.println(re);
        }
        
    }
    public static void permute(List<List<String>> lists, List<List<String>> result, int depth, String current) {
        if (depth == lists.size()) {
            List<String> current_list = new ArrayList<>();
            current_list = current.chars().mapToObj(e -> Character.toString((char)e))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            Collections.reverse(current_list);
            result.add(current_list);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lists.get(depth).size(); i++) {
            permute(lists, result, depth+1, current + lists.get(depth).get(i));
        }
    }
}
```